# Arbitrary Swizzling on Fixed-Size Vectors

Tags: c++, templates, traits, auto

For practice with templates and such, I'm working on implementing fixed-size template math types for an arbitrary number dimensions.

**Premise:**
I have a base **rvec** class that abstracts the data used by a **tvec** class (not shown or necessary) that implements the math of vectors. The base class exists in two forms- a value-type and reference-type, distinguished via template specialization using a boolean flag.

The reference type is my current solution for implementing arbitrary swizzling. I was using traits to enable/disable overloads based on the type (pointer or non-pointer), but that wasn't working well for partial specialization with the variadic needed for my swizzle (it did work, but required abusing traits and templates to a degree I didn't feel was very maintainable- I may go back to that though).

**Problem:** The following totally works as intended! There is one thing that really bugs me. When creating an automatic variable and assigning it to the swizzle, it stores the reference-type instead of storing the value-type. I don't really want the end-user to ever be able to create a reference-type. This data structure should emulate or behave like POD as much as possible.

The reference-type ONLY exists so I can method-chain from the swizzle. The sad thing is that if auto isn't used everything works just fine.

```
template<unsigned S, typename T=float, bool B=false>
class rvec
{
    std::array<T, S> data;
public:
    float  operator[] (unsigned i) const { return data[i]; }
    float &operator[] (unsigned i)       { return data[i]; }

    // Returns reference-type!
    template<unsigned ...I, unsigned N = sizeof...(I)>
    rvec<N, T, true> swizzle()  { return{ {&data[I]...} }; }

    // Value-Type!
    template<unsigned ...I, unsigned N = sizeof...(I)>
    rvec<N, T> swizzle() const  { return{ { data[I]... } }; }

    rvec(const std::initializer_list<T> &d) { std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), data.begin()); }
    rvec() {}
};
```

This is my reference type. It should offer both read and write, but I don't ever want the user, intentionally or unintentionally, storing this in a variable. It should only exist to method-chain changes to the value-type that calls the swizzle.

I tried privatizing assignment/copy constructors, but the compiler doesn't switch to using the correct swizzling function (from the value-type) or take advantage of the implicit type conversion (in the reference-type).

```
template<unsigned S, typename T>
class rvec<S,T,true>
{
    std::array<T*, S> data;
    rvec(const std::initializer_list<T*> &d) { std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), data.begin()); }

    template<unsigned N, typename T, bool B> friend class rvec;
    rvec &operator=(const rvec &o);
    rvec(const rvec &o);
public:
    // same access behavior as value-type
    float  operator[] (unsigned i) const { return *data[i]; }
    float &operator[] (unsigned i)       { return *data[i]; }
    // convert to value-type.
    operator rvec<S, T, false>()
    {
        rvec<S, T, false> r;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < S; ++i)
            r[i] = *data[i];
        return r;
    }
    // write to the original values
    rvec &operator=(const rvec<S, T, false> &o)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < S; ++i)
            &data[i] = o[i];
    }

    template<unsigned ...I, unsigned N = sizeof...(I)>
    rvec<N, T, true> swizzle() const { return{ { data[I]... } }; }
};
```

What's a good way to prevent my reference-type from ever existing outside of the swizzle? I need write access and want to keep fixed-sizes.

Thanks!